# Why do I get a type inference error in this example and how to do it better?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following typescript example I have a function `getPerson` that simply takes an object and a key to look up the value. However the input object is a Partial Generic:

```
export type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: string;
}

export type People = Record<string, Person>;

function getPerson<D extends People>(partialData: Partial<D>, key: string): Person {

    if (!partialData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        throw new Error("key not found in dataContainer.incompleteDataSet");
    }

    return partialData[key]; // TS Lint Error here
}
```

This code seems to work as I want it to, however I get a TS Lint Error in the return statement:

```
TS2322: Type 'D[string] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person
```

In the function `getPerson`, the Generic `D` should specify what kind of `People` we have, e.g. `D` could be a `Parents` type with keys `mom` and `dad`.

```
export type Parents = {    
    mom: Person,
    dad: Person,    
}

const parentsData: Partial<Parents> = {
    mom: {
        name: "Ann",
        age: "55",
    }
}
const mom: Person = getPerson(parentsData, "mom");
console.log(mom);
```

However `getPerson` should also be open to work with other Person-structures like this:

```
const grandParentsData: Partial<Grandparents> = getGrandParentsData(); 
const grandma: Person = getPerson(grandParentsData, "grandma");
```

The best way I found to express this was `<D extends People>` next to `getPerson`. That might cause my linting problem though, because `D` would be allowed to have other key-values than just `<string, Person>` as defined in `People`. Am I right? Do you have any ideas how to do this better?

What I am looking for is not a better way to structure my data but to improve `getPerson`. (In my real project it is impossible to change the data structures right now).

Here is link to a [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKwoGcIDs4C8cA3gFBwVy4CGAtsAFxxYxQCWuA5gNzmXWdGzVhx6kAvqVKhIsBMlQYIYADaoiAJWABjaABMAPC3ZcANOkw5cAPl6kAZgFdc2mGzxxBMDNjwGAInCgMMC4elgWymrWABRg1LBs1Cr+1DDUTGgJbskB1uYA1sCITMaiAJSZlh5kfBRs9nAxAITxicmp6QB0ABbUWADyAO64aFDKmEgxRYjl5SR1lBQwPeNDVMDrAKJQ41AxAEQzVBDw9hDOenAccHpp1ADCeOkcmF0curSqwCGd1ADKPwO5V4S0kiygP0cUHwbRyKXuAG0ZgBdXjgmTQeBIFDoBKhGARIjEJaLWgQWhVXy4UyLO56KlWcyUCRSXS4FhwNoErB-TLZJIqAxZSG4QnWQgLJbkylSpaUGj0JgHACCuFwB1p8v4gmVAFY9ZrFpJJOzOTLGR4iF4fFY4vixbz7uYDjLgbwzRA1F0VBBODEZSCgA).

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`partialData.hasOwnProperty` does not act as a type guard. (It can't act as one even in principle, since `key` is dynamic)

The simplest solution is to use a not null assertion:

```
function getPerson<D extends People>(partialData: Partial<D>, key: string): Person {
    if (!partialData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        throw new Error("key not found in dataContainer.incompleteDataSet");
    }
    return  partialData[key]!;
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

You can get a fully typed version, but it's semantics are a bit different:

```
function getPerson<D extends People>(partialData: Partial<D>, key: string): Person {
    const value = partialData[key]
    if (!value) {
        throw new Error("key not found in dataContainer.incompleteDataSet");
    }
    return value;
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

The above version tests if the value of the property is not undefined. Indeed this seems to be a more type safe behavior, since just because the object has the property, it does not mean it is not `undefined`  (`({ age: undefined }).hasOwnProperty ("age")` is true, but `({ age: undefined })['age']` is undefined)